# Need some ninja technique to update a whole lotta of values from repeater to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

I have a repeater with about 100 rows, and 4 columns in each row. something like this table:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Username        HasIpod        HasGymMembership        HasCar
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
User1            chcekbox        checkbox               checkbox
User2            chcekbox        checkbox               checkbox
User3            chcekbox        checkbox               checkbox
User4            chcekbox        checkbox               checkbox
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

well, you get the idea.

The admin can tick/untick any box anytime and click on a "Save" button at the end of page and thats when I need to update the database. I need to add a row in one of the table if a certain checkbox is checked, delete it if its unchecked.

I can just loop through the repeater and VERY EASILY do it with each row. but my concern is that, at the worst case, this will use about 100 rows X 3 = 300 database accesses. Thats bad right?

I thought of concatenating all values into a form of csv.. something like:

```
user1id,1,0,1;user1id,0,1,1
```

just a list of userid, its values separated with `,` and the next user's values separated with `;` and in the database I can just use a split function and a bunch of while loop and update accordingly.

but It just doesnt satisfy me for some reason. Is there a better way to deal with a such a situation? I am sure this is not a unique case, what do you guys do in a scenario? any insight about being a super fast "ninja" in this (with as little db access as possible) would be great.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of csv you can use xml, like this:

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(1000)
SET @XmlDocument = N'<ROOT>
<User Username="user1" HasIpod="1" HasGymMembership="1" HasCar="0" />
<User Username="user2" HasIpod="1" HasGymMembership="0" HasCar="1" />
<User Username="user3" HasIpod="0" HasGymMembership="1" HasCar="0" />
<User Username="user4" HasIpod="0" HasGymMembership="0" HasCar="1" />
</ROOT>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/ROOT/User',1)
      WITH (Username  varchar(100),
            HasIpod bit,
            HasGymMembership bit,
            HasCar bit)

/* ... update your tables here ... */

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

**UPDATE:** 
another way, assuming you use dirty state

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int
DECLARE @XmlDocument nvarchar(1000)
SET @XmlDocument = N'<root>
    <added>
        <ipod userID="1" />
        <ipod userID="2" />
        <gym userID="1" />
        <gym userID="3" />
        <car userID="2" />
        <car userID="4" />
    </added>
    <removed>
        <ipod userID="3" />
        <ipod userID="5" />
        <gym userID="4" />
        <gym userID="5" />
        <car userID="1" />
        <car userID="3" />
    </removed>
</root>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlDocument

insert into HasIPodTable SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/root/added/ipod',1) WITH (userID  int)
delete HasIPodTable where userID in (SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/root/removed/ipod',1) WITH (userID  int))

/* and the same for the others ... */

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

that's of course assuming you have 3 tables (`ipod`, `gym`, `car`). if not, then just update the `Users` table

Comment: Combine this with some server side dirty mechanism, and you're golden.

Comment: sorry but doing this in database would require passing all values to it, doesnt it? and I dont the use of xml here. can you please explain?

Comment: you create the XML on the server, and pass it as a XML document to the database (everything before the EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument). The database then knows how to treat that document as a table, and you could use a simple stored proc to do the inserting/updating/deleting. So all you have is a single database call.

Comment: thank you. I was waiting for [Paul Chavez's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978753/need-some-ninja-technique-to-update-a-whole-lotta-of-values-from-repeater-to-data/4979334#4979334) to reply that seemed to be the easiest. when I didnt get any reply I fiddled with this method a bit and finally got it to work. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider adding two things, a dirty condition for each field, so you are only updating values that have changed and use the "IN" & "UNION" clauses in sql, something like this:

```
delete from HasIPodTable
where UserID IN (firstUncheckedUserID, secondUncheckedUserID, ...)

insert into HasIPodTable
select firstCheckedUserID
UNION
select secondCheckedUserID
...
```

This will reduce your database calls to 2 per table, and one per changed value.  You are still performing a write for every changed value.

Do  you need the checkbox values in separate tables?
Can you change the schema to denormalize the tables and merge them into a single user attribute table with a field for each column in your grid.

If you can can, you can replace the delete/insert pairs with a single update statement, once for each row.  This will increase the number of times you access the database, but reduce the number write statements.  So you may want to profile where your latency/performance delays are greatest.  Is it over the wire from your application to your database?  Or is it in the I/O inherent in the database?

Comment: firstly, the database and application both are in a dedicated server, so I would say they are local. My concern is that I dont know what's worst, multiple database access or write. I cant avoid writes as the checkboxes go onto a different tables depending on values (and I cant change this since its quite old and many parts in application uses these tables) so I cant reduce number of writes. So I was wondering if I could reduce access atleast

Comment: @y34h's & @sweko's answers will get you there, though it doesn't feel elegant to me.  You were worried about passing values through viewstate, but you could cache the dataset on the server.  ASP.NET has ways to help you hack around the stateless nature of HTTP.  From a performance perspective, because the app server and db server share a physical server, I suspect latency is caused more by I/O than commands.  But testing & profiling is the only way to tell for sure.  DB performance is very dependent on your hardware and schema.  So there is no one size fits all solution to performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm neither a web or C# developer... But how about some "dirty state mechanism" and only persist those rows that were modified?

In other words, when you're about to save then compare each row with copy that is "old row" (I guess you have some unique identifier to match old and new row with) and only save if the two copies doesn't equal.

Comment: hm... dirty state mechanism would involve storing all that information in someplace retrievable. and since webpages are stateless, the only way to do that would be in a viewstate or session - which could result in a large overhead (while transfering the requests). wouldnt that be a problem?

Comment: For only 100 rows it seems to me that there should be no perfomance problem storing a copy of the rows somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reduce the I/O load on the database? or improve perceived performance by the user?

Instead of trying to optimize the database updates, since there are only 100 or so rows to worry about, how about introducing AJAX into your UI so that updates happen in near real time as the administrator clicks each check box?

Look into these pages for more details, or select another AJAX framework that you like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx (overview)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx (introduction)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398890.aspx (partial page update example)

Comment: Hi, I was looking for something EXACTLY like this. I did think of this. But the trouble was, how do I get the checkbox to pass an argument? onCheckChanged will not be bound the the repeater and i cant get the row details. Also, checkbox do not have CommandArgument.. how would I go to do this? (I am familiar with ajax, javascript too)

Comment: sorry @iamserious, it may take a while before I can prototype something.  I've moved away from ASP.NET so I don't have an immediate answer for you.